# 文字列の並びを逆順に表示したいです。

Tags: java

```
import java.util.Scanner;

class 
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        String endStr;          //読み込みを終了する文字列
        endStr = new String("end");
        StringBuilder strBul;   //組み立てた文字列
        strBul = new StringBuilder();
        String str;
        System.out.print("文字列を入力 : ");
        str = sc.next();
        while (str.equals(endStr) != true)
        {
            strBul.reverse();

            System.out.println("[組み立てた文字列] " + strBul);
            System.out.print("文字列を入力");
            str = sc.next();
        }
        sc.close();
    }
}
```

reverse()メソッド？を使って文字列の並びを逆順にしたいのですが、うまく表示されません。
どのようにしたらいいですか？

Comment: 入力した文字列がStringBuilder にセットされていないようですが・・、また毎回reverseするのでなく最後にすればいいのではないですか？

Comment: セットはどのようにするのですか？
reverseの使い方はこのような形でいいですか？

なにもわからなくてすいません＞＜

Comment: 入力例と期待する出力があると回答する側にとって何がやりたいのか理解しやすいです。

Comment: 文字列を入力 : loop
[変換後の文字列]　pool
文字列を入力 : part
[変換後の文字列]　trap
文字列を入力 : end

このようにしたいです。よろしくお願いします＞＜

Answer (score 1, accepted):

それぞれの入力文字列にreverseを適用するということなので、

```
StringBuilder strBul;   //組み立てた文字列
strBul = new StringBuilder();
```

の部分は削除してwhileブロックに移動して
`strBul.reverse();` 
を
`StringBuilder strBul = new StringBuilder(str).reverse();`
に変更する

でいいかと思います。

Comment: ありがとうございます＞＜
できました！
二度も助けていただきありがとうございます！